# shell : how to start taking inputs from a file some time (say two minutes) after command execution starts

Tags: shell, sleep, wait, io-redirection

I have to run a script, which takes app. 1 minute for initialization, and then asks inputs from the user.

If I do like

```
bash-3.2$ java -d64 -jar myJarFile.jar < input_file
```

It takes input instantly and when myJarFile.jar actually needs inputs, it gets nothing.

So, how I can I tackle this?

Comment: What if you `sleep 120 && java -d64 -jar myJarFile.jar < input_file`?

Comment: it sleeps for 120 seconds and then execute java -d64 -jar myJarFile.jar < input_file"   ,i.e. effectively no change.

I need it start executing.....but start taking inputs form the file after 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use expect script.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
spawn ./run.sh
expect "\[Next]> " {send "Next\r"}
interact
```

In this example, it runs run.sh and asynchronously wait for  this string on terminal "[Next]>". whenever it gets this message on terminal, it sends Next as input to the script.

Answer (score 1):

According to your prompt you're using BASH, so you should be able to use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) that includes a `sleep`. Example:

```
$ seq 1 20 >numbers
$ cat < <(sleep 5; cat numbers)
# 5 second pause and then the contents of the 'numbers' file is output
```

So with your command you would run:

```
java -d64 -jar myJarFile.jar < <(sleep 120; cat input_file)
```